# QML: set width based on left/right anchors of other Items

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml

How do I set the width of a QML item based on the values of other items' anchors.left and anchors.right? Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Rectangle {
        width: parent.right - parent.left
        height: parent.height
    }

}
```

Obviously, this is only a simple example because I could just use `width: parent.width`, but that will not work in general. For instance, if the two anchors are on different items:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Rectangle {
        anchors.left: parent.left
        width: other.left - parent.left
        height: parent.height
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: other
        anchors.right: parent.right
        width: 123
        height: parent.height
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is not it general? Please indicate a particular case.

Comment: could explain why that last example does not work

Comment: I think it is because the values of left and right are not integers, so arithmetic operators cannot be used.

Comment: my initial question was in the sense of why do not you use `width: parent.width`?

Comment: Thanks, that line of questions made realize that I *could* use the `width`s of the other items, combined with their `x` values to calculate their `left` and `right` anchor points.

Comment: I never understood your problem, the anchors make a binding between the `x`, `y`, `x + width` and `y + height`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, though it is a bit messy. For the following code that does not work:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Rectangle {
        id: other1
        anchors.left: parent.left
        width: 43 
        height: parent.height
    }

    Rectangle {
        anchors.left: other1.right 
        width: other2.left - other1.right
        height: parent.height
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: other2
        anchors.right: parent.right
        width: 123
        height: parent.height
    }

}
```

Replace `other1.right` with `other1.x + other1.width` and `other2.left` with `other2.x`, which gives us:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Rectangle {
        id: other1
        anchors.left: parent.left
        width: 43 
        height: parent.height
    }

    Rectangle {
        anchors.left: other1.right 
        width: other2.x - (other1.x + other1.width)
        height: parent.height
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: other2
        anchors.right: parent.right
        width: 123
        height: parent.height
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding unnecessary complexity to a simple problem.

As long as you want to anchor the item to its siblings or direct parent, you don't need to manually calculate the width of your item.

See [Positioning with Anchors](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html).

Just anchor the left **and** right values:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Rectangle {
        id: other1
        anchors.left: parent.left
        width: 43 
        height: parent.height
    }

    Rectangle {
        anchors.left: other1.right 
        anchors.right: other2.left
        // width: other2.x - (other1.x + other1.width) // absolutely not necessary
        height: parent.height
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: other2
        anchors.right: parent.right
        width: 123
        height: parent.height
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know how to use anchors.left/right, but it doesn't work for my purposes. The example I provided was greatly simplified,  but I'm trying to set the width of an item that is in a Row, but Rows do no allow their children to set anchors.